# Define string array

Tags: c, arrays, string, c-preprocessor

I would like to define an array of string like that:

```
#define sup (const char**) ("string1", "string2")
```

but it fails when I try to print the first string:

```
printf("The string: %s\n",sup[0]);
```

how to do it in the proper way?

Answer (score 6):

I would advice against doing this with macros altogether, but if you are really interested in what is going on with the code --more than in how this should actually be tackled, here is an explanation.

There is a simple issue in the code, and a more obscure one. The very simple is that to declare an array you don't use parenthesis but rather curly braces:

```
#define sup (const char**){"str1", "str2"} // still wrong!!
```

The less simple issue is that **arrays are not pointers**. The curly brace initializer can be used to initialize an array of two `const char*`, but that is not the same as a `const char**`. If you change the code to:

```
#define sup (const char*[2]){"str1", "str2" }
```

It should work.

What is going on under the hood with the previous version? Well, the compiler is seeing the declaration of a pointer (well, casting to a pointer) and the initializer. It is assuming that you want to initialize the pointer with the first element (incompatible pointer, but the cast is explicit... you must know what you want if you *forced the cast*), and then ignore the remainder. Basically the compiler translates your code to [*]:

```
#define sup (const char**)"str1"
```

And that will cause havoc at runtime. It is interesting to note that if you had used a proper variable and then initialized the pointer with it, it would have worked, because while *arrays are not pointers* (I insist, keep that in mind) arrays do decay into pointers:

```
const char* tmp[] = { "hi", "there" };
const char** sup = tmp;              // fine, tmp decays into &tmp[0]
```

[*] There's a bit of handwaving there... the compiler translates the code, once inserted at the place of use of the macro by the preprocessor, but the translation is equivalent to what I wrote if you were to edit the macro manually.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your answer it made my ideas more clear on this topic.

However, using `#define sup (const char*[2]){"str1", "str2" }
` if i do `printf("String: %s\n",sup[0]);` it gives me back this error: "error C2059: syntax error : '{' "

Comment: @Beppe macros simply expand their text in place, so sup[0] becomes (const char*[2]){"str1", "str2" }[0] which is a syntax error. So you need #define sup ((const char*[2]){"str1", "str2" }) -- note the parentheses. But macros like this are just a bad idea.

Comment: Since everyone is telling me that this is a bad idea, I'm switching to another solution, like the one that Matteo Italia suggests.
Again, thanks everyone for your precious help.

Comment: Note that in C, string literals are arrays of `char`, not `const char`, and thus string literal expressions usually decay to type `char *`.

Answer (score 2):

I think that doing this kind of preprocessor tricks, especially with arrays, isn't such a good idea. You should instead have a real global string table, like this:

```
const char const * sup[]={"String 1", "String 2", "String 3"};
```

in one of the `.c` files, and put its `extern` declaration in a header to be included wherever such strings are needed:

```
extern const char const * sup[];
```

(the first `const` is to avoid modifications to each string literal - which is UB -, the second to avoid replacing the pointers stored in `sup`; if you want to allow this last action, remove the second `const`)

An alternative approach would be to define `sup` directly in the header as a `static` global variable (i.e. with internal linkage); I've seen this done before with integer constants to make sure they are immediately known to the compiler in every translation unit (so it can put them as immediate values in the generated assembly), but I don't think that with string pointers it can give any significant performance boost.

Answer (score 0):

I have a header that is common to all my projects.

```
#define MAX_STUDENTS 3
char STUDENT[] = { "Manny", "Joe", "Jack" };
```

The code looks like:

```
for( int i=0; i<MAX_STUDENTS; i++ )
{ Do Something with STUDENT[i]; }
```

Claude

Comment: Sorry!  Cannot figure out how to drive this input editor.